# What is the expected value of this Markov chain - Secret Santa problem?

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, mathematical-modeling

**How this problem came about:**
There's 10 of us participating in a Secret Santa gift exchange. The issue is that someone might draw his/her own name and we start over.

**My solution:**
One person at a time draws a name from the "bowl" and that person needs to make sure that he/she has not drawn himself/herself before the next person's turn. If someone draws his/her own name, half of those who already drew a name should replace their drawn names back to the "bowl". For example, say I am the sixth person to draw a name and I draw my own, then I'll ask 2 of those who already drew a name to put theirs back and take part in the drawing once more. (Round down the half of 5 to get 2.)

**Definition:**
redraw - each time that a person draws his/her name and others put their names back

**What I found out:**
Whenever I simulate this process 1,000,000 times, the expected number of redraws is 1.36 or 1.37. See https://onlinegdb.com/ryuUmT-6S.

> **Can you prove this algebraically?**

Comment: Which half of the players return the name they drew? Is it random, the first ones to have drawn, what? From the code it looks like it is random, but that should be specified in the question.

Comment: Assume randomly since it's up to the person to choose who replaces their drawn names back.

Comment: That said I'm just trying to get a feel for how small you can even make the state space and honestly I don't see how you can get below 3 million states. (The naive way to do it is to have $11^{10}$=about 26 million states, even though a lot of those states are inaccessible.)

Comment: @Ian I think it's possible to get a model with $164$
 (or thereabouts) states. However, enumerating the states is a somewhat complicated and error-prone process, and I'm not yet confident I've got them all, or that all the ones I think I've got are legitimate. Setting up the transition matrix, even with a program or script, also looks like it would be a very tedious process, which I probably won't be prepared to do myself. However, I think the answer to the OP's question, "Can you prove this algebraically? should be "yes, provided you're willing to do the necessary drudge work."

Comment: @lonzaleggiera I am impressed that you can get so few states, there must be a lot of symmetry exploitation going on there. It seemed to me that most of the symmetry that I could come up with to exploit was being destroyed by the "random return" behavior. (Also my 26 *million* in the previous comment was supposed to be 26 *billion*.)

Comment: Yes, I suppose the definition of the states does exploit some sort of symmetry, although it wasn't sufficiently obvious for me to notice that that's what's going on.  It's also true that I did miss a few states, whose number now stands at $169$.

Comment: Is it possible to arrive at it inductively, you think?

Comment: You haven't defined who draws when. Of course, before the first redraw, that doesn't matter, but afterwards it does. Your code seems to be inconsistent in this regard. In line $54$, `while (toChooseList.get(chosenIndex).equals(origList.get(current)))` seems to imply that it's always the same person who draws whenever there's a certain number of names left in the bowl; but that can't be right, since the people who put their names back are chosen randomly, so that person might have retained their name and others should be drawing.

Comment: @joriki  I read the code the same way.  As the code is written  it looks to me like the individuals named Lolo, Lola, Mhond, John, Allan, JR, Reylyn, Mhel, Hannah and Cath always draw from the bowl in that order.  If the $\ n^\text{th}\ $ person to choose gets his or her own name, then the individuals who have to redraw are always taken to be the $\ 
\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\ $ individuals who have most recently drawn from the bowl, while the $\ 
\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\ $ names that get returned to the bowl are chosen randomly.

Comment: As simulated in the code, there would appear to be a probability of $\ \frac{1}{10}\cdot\frac{1}{9}\cdot\frac{1}{8}\cdot\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{1440}\ $ that Lolo could draw Lola's name, Lola draw Lolo's, Mhond draw his or her own, and the papers with Lola's and Mhond's name then get returned to the bowl, leaving Lolo, who will never draw again, with his or her own name.  This seems to me to make it rather implausible that the code will return the correct answer for the problem as described here.  My guess is that the estimate of the expected number of redraws is too low.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera: You seem to at least have a clear idea what "the problem as described here" is :-) I don't see any definition of who draws when. We can only assume that the next person to draw should be uniformly randomly chosen among those who currently don't have a name.

Comment: Yes, I believe I understand the problem "as described here" (though still conceding that I may well be mistaken about that), and was assuming that the next person to draw shoild be chosen randomly.  But in [this code](https://www.onlinegdb.com/ryuUmT-6S), which I understood was supposed to be an accurate simulation of the process described here, the next person to draw *does not appear to be chosen randomly*.

Comment: My contention, therefore, is that this code does *not* give an accurate simulation of the process *as described here.*  Therefore, the expected number of redraws it returns is almost certainly *not* an accurate estimate for the expected number redraws in the process *as described here*, and the answer to your final question is thus almost certainly "no", although I do think it's possible to calculate the correct expected number of redraws algebraically.

Comment: [Here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/S1Dwb-6pr) is a version of the code which I've modified to try and get it to simulate the process described here accurately.  Contrary to my guess that the expected number of redraws would be larger, it has actually turned out to be smaller.  Every time I've run the modified code, it has given $1.33$ as the expected number of redraws.  I should acknowledge, however, that I'm almost totally unacquainted with Java, so my modified version of the code needs to be checked carefully by someone familiar with that language to ensure that it's doing what it should be.